# How to I fix this if/else tree? PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to program a sub-system for students on my website, I tried using these if/else statements  to determine some outputs if the parameters match with the user information they have. So if a user is  a student they can contact other people that are students and cant contact other users that are not students, and vice versa. The code I tried is below. The problem is that the code shows the error message and the message buttons at the same time whether or not the user is or is not a student. TIP: This PHP code is in a .phtml file, hence the amount of PHP opening and closing tags.

```
<?php if($dc['user']['student'] !== 0){ ?>
    <?php if(Dc_IsStudent($dc['popover']['user_id']) == true){ ?>
        <div class="user-button user-follow-button"><?php echo Dc_GetFollowButton($dc['popover']['user_id']); ?></div>
        <div class="user-button message-button"><?php echo Dc_GetMessageButton($dc['popover']['user_id']); ?></div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(Dc_IsStudent($dc['popover']['user_id']) == false) { ?>
        <?php echo $dc['lang']['student_contact_warning'];  ?> 
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($dc['user']['student'] !== 1){ ?>
    <?php if(Dc_IsStudent($dc['popover']['user_id']) == false){ ?>
        <div class="user-button user-follow-button"><?php echo Dc_GetFollowButton($dc['popover']['user_id']); ?></div>
        <div class="user-button message-button"><?php echo Dc_GetMessageButton($dc['popover']['user_id']); ?></div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(Dc_IsStudent($dc['popover']['user_id']) == true) { ?>
        <?php echo $dc['lang']['student_contact_warning'];  ?> 
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are obliged you to open and close the tags after each line. The fact it is in a `.phtml` file is not a reason in my eyes. The result is that your code is unreadable  and very hard to debug.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It might help to just type != instead of !== because the latter means that the $dc['user']['student'] must be exactly the type of zero or one. (I don't know if it is in your example but it might be an issue). I agree with @PierreFrançois about the unreadability and you don't need so many opening and close tags.

Comment: @PierreFrançois Yes I can agree with that part. I will improve on my code layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do yourself a favour and start to use variables for repeated functions, and look up PHP's HereDoc to allow you to simplify your code. I think you'll agree the following is clearer.

The question now is what values you expect in your conditions. Run the following and check that the outputted `IsStudent` and `Student` are what you expect.

```php
<?php
$Student=$dc['user']['student'];
$IsStudent=Dc_IsStudent($dc['popover']['user_id']);
$Dc_FollowBut=Dc_GetFollowButton($dc['popover']['user_id']);
$Dc_MessageBut=Dc_GetMessageButton($dc['popover']['user_id']);


echo"IsStudent: $IsStudent<br>";
echo"Student: $Student<br>";


if($Student!=0){
    if($IsStudent==true){
        echo<<<EOC
        <div class="user-button user-follow-button">$Dc_FollowBut</div>
        <div class="user-button message-button">$Dc_MessageBut</div>
EOC;
    }else{
        echo $dc['lang']['student_contact_warning'];
    }
}

if($Student!=1){
    if($IsStudent==false){
        echo<<<EOC
        <div class="user-button user-follow-button">$Dc_FollowBut</div>
        <div class="user-button message-button">$Dc_MessageBut</div>
EOC;
    }else{
        echo $dc['lang']['student_contact_warning'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The solution your provided causes PHP to show the error Unexpected $EOF

Comment: The reason for that is the indenting. The closing identifier of HereDoc delimiters need to be at the start of the line. I have updated it.

Comment: I modified the code a bit, and it works perfectly! Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would first make the PHP code more clear. Then you will see that you didn't close some tags.

```php
<?php
if ($dc['user']['student'] !== 0) { 
   if (Dc_IsStudent($dc['popover']['user_id']) == true) { 
     echo '<div class="user-button user-follow-button">';
     echo Dc_GetFollowButton ($dc['popover']['user_id']); 
     echo '</div>' . "\n";
     echo '<div class="user-button message-button">';
     echo Dc_GetMessageButton($dc['popover']['user_id']);
     echo '</div>' . "\n";
   } else {
     echo $dc['lang']['student_contact_warning']; 
   }
}

if ($dc['user']['student'] !== 1){
  if (Dc_IsStudent($dc['popover']['user_id']) == false){
    echo '<div class="user-button user-follow-button">';
    echo Dc_GetFollowButton($dc['popover']['user_id']);
    echo '</div>' . "\n";
    echo '<div class="user-button message-button">';
    echo Dc_GetMessageButton($dc['popover']['user_id']); 
    echo '</div>' . "\n";
  } else {
    echo $dc['lang']['student_contact_warning'];
  }
}
?>
```

Now we can start analyzing the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    if($dc['user']['student'] != 0){

        if(Dc_IsStudent($dc['popover']['user_id']) == true){ 

            echo '<div class="user-button user-follow-button">'. Dc_GetFollowButton($dc['popover']['user_id']) .'</div>';
            echo '<div class="user-button message-button">'. Dc_GetMessageButton($dc['popover']['user_id']) .'</div>';

        } else { 

            echo $dc['lang']['student_contact_warning'];   

        } 

    } else if($dc['user']['student'] != 1){ 

        if(Dc_IsStudent($dc['popover']['user_id']) == false){ 

            echo '<div class="user-button user-follow-button">'. Dc_GetFollowButton($dc['popover']['user_id']) .'</div>';
            echo '<div class="user-button message-button">'. Dc_GetMessageButton($dc['popover']['user_id']) .'</div>';

        } else {

            echo $dc['lang']['student_contact_warning']; 

        }

    } 

?>
```

Try putting it in one block, rather than 2 seperate blocks. If-else blocks are meant like that. I would prefer using cases here, though i tried cleaning this up a bit for you to see whats going on.

I agree with @jbes in the other awnser that you should use variables, to make things a lot easier to read. i didn't do this, but i totally agree on that part.

A typo can be made quickly if you constantly run only if blocks, with else, you can point to a different actions in the same if, without closing the complete block. Now I don't know if `$dc['user']['student']` can only be 0 or 1, but else you can toss away the complete `else-if` statement and just change it to `else` to make it more cleaner. Also to check `if not 0` leaves open for a lot of interpretation, what if the value is 2 or 48644. it would always trigger both blocks, so you may want to swap it around to check if the value equals 1 or 0.

I hope this points you in the right direction

Comment: This helped. I will also will use variables more often, you bring up a valid point on how useful they can be.

Comment: If it awnsered your question, please accept it as the awnser and give it a vote up ;)

Comment: What if a  regular user was trying to contact a student? In that case it would display an error message. Would I just add to the block?

Comment: You ll have to elaborate that through your code. Do you mean if `$dc['user']['student'] != 0)` (not student) and the `Dc_IsStudent($dc['popover']['user_id']) == false)` (so in this case, the else block)? You can just mod the else block basically